# Postgresql + array type + PDO + GIN index how to make them work?

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, indexing, pdo

I have this (working) query:

```
SELECT * from "DB".pages WHERE topic @> '{football}';
```

Notice that there is an array type column (topic) indexed with GIN.

I have to implement this in PhP with PDO. I tried with

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * from "DB".pages WHERE topic @> \'{?}\' ORDER BY pgname');
$stmt->execute([$topic]);
$rs= $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Without success:

```
"SQLSTATE[08P01]: <<Unknown error>>: 7 ERROR:  bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement \"pdo_stmt_00000001\" requires 0"
```

How to perform this?

Comment: Please show PHP code. Likely the placeholder should not be quoted.

Comment: See code above, edited.

Comment: Don't quote the placeholder. Put the braces into the value. e.g.`WHERE topic @> ?` and then `$stmt->execute(['{' . $topic . '}']);`